# Accessing a Bean Property Dynamically using EL

Tags: java, jsp, el

I need to access a property of a bean whose name is stored in a variable using EL in a JSP page.

If I were to access a property named "description", then I would go ${bean.description}, but since the name of the property is stored in the variable "name", I have no idea how I would do it in EL.

Is this possible? If not, does anyone have a workaround?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the form `${bean[name]}`. More explanation is available in § JSP.2.3.4 of the [Java ServerPages 2.0 Specification.](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr152/)