# iterate over properties with ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, xhtml

From a xhtml page, is anyhow possible something like this?

```
<tbody>
<ui:repeat value="#{listOfObject}" var="obj">
            <tr>
                <ui:repeat value="#{propertiesOfObject}" var="prop">
                    <td>#{obj.prop}</td>
                </ui:repeat>
            </tr>
</ui:repeat>
</tbody>
```

In other words, I'd like to get a table where both the columns and the rows are parameters. I can't find a way to access the "obj.prop".

Comment: Don't have much experience with ui:repeat but I believe your var will the variable name of the object so I think you would want to do `#{prop.nameOfPropertyOnThisObject}` in the el

Comment: Wait is `#{propertiesOfObject}` a collection? Because if not, I don't think you can iterate over it like that

Comment: It is, but dot notation did not work. Problem solved now, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `#{propertiesOfObject}` is a list of the property names (build via reflection if needed) and just use

```
#{obj[prop]}
```

See also

- [Accessing a Bean Property Dynamically using EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713657/accessing-a-bean-property-dynamically-using-el)

Comment: propertiesOfObject was indeed a list of the property names built via reflection inside a Bean. It worked, thanks. Regarding the similarity with the linked question, this case does not involve a jsp file.
Cheers.

Comment: Learn to think in **generic** problems. Don't 'narrow' things down too much, easier to find solution then. The Problem/question is in EL, not JSF specifically (and jsf could use JSP too).